# How to install an apk using the PackageInstaller class?

Tags: java, android, apk

**Hello everyone**

### My problem

I have the need to install an apk from an inputstream and the PackageInstaller class is the only one that allows me to do it, but my current code does not work, it gives me the typical error "The application has stopped." And I do not know where I failed. And I do not know where the error occurs.

**The code**

```
public static void installPackage(Context context, InputStream inputStream)
    throws IOException {
PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(new PackageInstaller
        .SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL));
PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

long sizeBytes = 0;

OutputStream out = null;
out = session.openWrite("my_app_session", 0, sizeBytes);

int total = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
int c;
while ((c = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    total += c;
    out.write(buffer, 0, c);
}
session.fsync(out);
inputStream.close();
out.close();

// fake intent
IntentSender statusReceiver = null;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
        1337111117, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

session.commit(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
session.close();
```

}

**Information that may be relevant:**

- I use an emulator with the version of android 4.1.2
- My application requests permission from SuperUsuario (Root), therefore the device has permissions of SuperUsuario

**If you know of any way to achieve my goal, I'll be happy to hear it. Thank you so much**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: See the above link for some general tips. In order for us to help you, we need more information starting with the stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: Sorry but this question is not duplicate if you realize I am mentioning another subject.Thanks

Comment: Did you actually read any of it and follow the suggestions?